# Access to a variable function from another function in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

there's a problem, I can not understand what I'm doing wrong ..

I want to get the value of the function of the other features in WordPress ..

This code replaces some parts of the code ..

I want to get the value of the argument variable words (it needs to go $attr['words']) and then use the other functions (new_quote).

```
    <?php
    /*
    * Plugin Name: Random Quotes
    */

    function random_quote($atts) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'path' => plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'quotes.txt',// default, if not set
        'label_new' => 'New Quote',
        'words' => 'no'   // yes or no 
        ), $atts ) );

        $temp = $attr['words']; // no
        ...

    }

    add_shortcode('randomquotes','random_quote');


    function new_quote(){
    global $temp;  // NULL
    /*
    global $attr;
    $temp = $attr['words']; // again NULL
    */
        ...

        if($temp == "no") {
        ...
        }
    }

   ...

?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe just can not get the value of this variable?

Comment: Where are you running this `new_quote()` function? And why do you need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to declare global $temp within your random_quote() function. Right now, random_quote() is using a local version of $temp, which is lost when the function is completed.

EDIT: Here's an example snippet

```
<?php
function test() {
  global $temp;
  $temp = 'no';
}
function my_test() {
  global $temp;

  var_dump($temp);
}

test();
my_test();
?>
```

Comment: What is returning NULL?

Comment: When a function is returned, then random_quote argument value (all right), but after the function is called new_quote, it returns NULL. This is an undefined value. But it should not be. I did all the functions of a global variable.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the updates you did to the code to try and get it to work?

Comment: Ok, in your random_quote function, add "global $temp;" "above extract( shortcode_atts( array("

Comment: Added to the beginning function, but the result did not change. NULL, in my opinion you can not do what I want ..

Comment: Do you ever call random_quote()? At least in the code you've given, you never call it. Therefore, $temp is not getting set and so it would be NULL.

Comment: This function is called with the shortcode. Well, yes, it is called up and running. I've tested it. That's just another reason the value of the function does not pass ..

Comment: Well, if you run the snippet of code I gave in my answer, you can see that the concept you're going for is possible. Another thing you can do is use the $GLOBALS array like in here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: I know about this global array. I used it. And the result was the same NULL.

Comment: Solved the problem this way: simply pass this argument as a parameter query using AJAX. Thanks for the response anyway!